# Seaborn heatmap showing incorrect x-axis values

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, heatmap, seaborn

I have a Pandas dataframe ("`df`") that looks something like:

```
      Variable1    Var2         Parameters           Values
0        10.000     1.1           0.296342         0.170009   
1        10.015     1.1           0.297013         0.168656   
2        10.030     1.1           0.297659         0.167326   
3        10.045     1.1           0.298282         0.166018   
4        10.060     1.1           0.298883         0.164731   
5        10.075     1.1           0.299462         0.162223
...         ...     ...                ...              ...
4038     24.565     1.0           0.563698         0.222069
```

Pivoting the dataframe using the following commands,

```
# Pivot dataframe
df = df.pivot('Var2', 'Variable1', 'Values')
```

I get the below pivoted dataframe:

```
Variable1    10.000    10.015    10.030    10.045    10.060    10.075  \
Var2                                                                  
1.0        0.219987  0.218130  0.216290  0.214465  0.212654  0.210856   
1.1        0.170009  0.168656  0.167326  0.166018  0.164731  0.163467   
1.2        0.133185  0.132202  0.131230  0.130269  0.129318  0.128378   
1.3        0.104472  0.103893  0.103312  0.102729  0.102147  0.101564   

Variable1    ...       24.865    24.880    24.895    24.910    24.925  
Var2         ...                
1.0          ...     0.212118  0.211691  0.211272  0.210860  0.210456     
1.1          ...     0.174883  0.174566  0.174257  0.173956  0.173662   
1.2          ...     0.147406  0.147154  0.146907  0.146664  0.146425   
1.3          ...     0.126780  0.126616  0.126456  0.126301  0.126150
```

However, when I try to image this using Seaborn's `heatmap` with the commands:

```
# Pivot dataframe
df = df.pivot('Var2', 'Variable1', 'Values')

# Create heatmap
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
sns.heatmap(df)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(20))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.ScalarFormatter())
plt.show()
```

I am getting a plot that shows the indices of Variable1 (0,1,2,3,4,...) whereas I need it to display the *values* of Variable1 (10, 10.015, 10.030, 10.045, etc.). I have included an example to illustrate.[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you include a portion of the pivoted `df` ?

Comment: @akilat90 -- Sorry about that, I got ahead of myself. I corrected my question. What I had earlier was the pivoted dataframe. I've included a sample of the original dataframe.

Comment: I followed the same steps as you on the sample data you provided and was able to obtain a heatmap using seaborn 0.7.1

Comment: @akilat90 - and your x-axis read the proper values for Variable1?  If it makes a difference, I am running this in a Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Yes, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying your sample data,

```
Variable1    Var2         Parameters           Values
    0        10.000     1.1           0.296342         0.170009   
    1        10.015     1.1           0.297013         0.168656   
    2        10.030     1.1           0.297659         0.167326   
    3        10.045     1.1           0.298282         0.166018   
    4        10.060     1.1           0.298883         0.164731   
    5        10.075     1.1           0.299462         0.162223
    4038     24.565     1.0           0.563698         0.222069

df = pd.read_clipboard()
df = df.pivot('Var2', 'Variable1', 'Values')
```

How `df` looks like:

```
Variable1    10.000    10.015    10.030    10.045    10.060    10.075  \
Var2                                                                    
1.0             NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
1.1        0.170009  0.168656  0.167326  0.166018  0.164731  0.162223   

Variable1    24.565  
Var2                 
1.0        0.222069  
1.1             NaN
```

just using `sns.heatmap(df)` returns,

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what was acting up, but simply running `sns.heatmap(df)` (as you suggested) resolved the issue. Thanks for the help -- TIL about `pd.read_clipboard()`.

Comment: One last thing -- how can I define my (start, end, increment) for my x-axis?

Comment: One way would be to use `ax = sns.heatmap(df)` and pass a numpy array to `ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels()`